# How to change this code to mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change this code to mouse hover.

```
// Login Form

$(function() {
    var button = $('#loginButton');
    var box = $('#loginBox');
    var form = $('#loginForm');
    button.removeAttr('href');
    button.mouseup(function(login) {
        box.toggle();
        button.toggleClass('active');
    });
    form.mouseup(function() { 
        return false;
    });
    $(this).mouseup(function(login) {
        if(!($(login.target).parent('#loginButton').length > 0)) {
            button.removeClass('active');
            box.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

When they hover on loginbox and Login form it should be visible otherwise the login form should be hidden.Right now when we click on it it shows up and when we click again it hides.

Comment: To me it seems like you found this code from somewhere and asking us to fix it for you. It is obvious that you did not even search for the answer on the google. If you did you would be able to find the answer for your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) instead of `mouseup`:

```
$(function() {
    var button = $('#loginButton');
    var box = $('#loginBox');
    var form = $('#loginForm');
    button.removeAttr('href');
    button.mouseover(function() {
        box.show();
        button.addClass('active');
    });
    button.mouseout(function() {
        box.hide();
        button.removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

From the docs:

> The mouseover event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer enters the element. Any HTML element can receive this event.

and

> The mouseout event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer leaves the element. Any HTML element can receive this event.

Here's a simple jsFiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/58TqM/1/

*NOTE*: You probably want to attach these events to a common parent of the box and button, so that the box doesn't hide when the mouse pointer leaves the button. Since the parent container will expand to fit the box when it gets shown, you will then be able to interact with the form until the mouse leaves the parent container area.

*EDIT*: Here's an updated version that uses CSS to achieve the intended effect, rather than manually showing/hiding the form: http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/58TqM/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just use mouseenter and mouseleave instead. The last event handler seems to close the loginBox when clicked outside it, and you don't really need it, but there's no harm in keeping it as an extra precaution so the user can close the box if mouseleave for some reason should fail :

```
$(function() {
    var button = $('#loginButton'),
        box    = $('#loginBox'),
        form   = $('#loginForm');

    button.removeAttr('href').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        box.toggle();
        button.toggleClass('active');
    });

    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if( !($(e.target).closest('#loginButton').length)) {
            button.removeClass('active');
            box.hide();
        }
    });
});
```